# Including External 3rd party scripts in Apostrophe CMS project

Tags: javascript, node.js, apostrophe-cms

How do you push a 3rd party script from a custom module in Apostrophe CMS?

I am following [this helpful tutorial](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/forms.html) to build a form for my Apostrophe CMS site. I am needing to put a reCaptcha thing on the form (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) and I am not following how to include the needed script from google. Note that I need to pass in a variable via the script file include url, ie: `<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>`

Is there already a widget created (like [Apostrophe-twitter](https://github.com/punkave/apostrophe-twitter)) that I could reference to understand how to include this extra script?

**Edit
I can get the job done by creating a block in my root template, ie: `{% block customAssets %}  {% endblock %}`, then 'populating' the block with my necessary includes from my contact-form-widget:widget.html file. Is there a better way of doing this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the lead developer of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

For most cases, you can call `pushAsset`, just as our modules do (there are examples in that tutorial you linked to), and populate the `public/css` and `public/js` subdirectories of your module with .less and .js files.

But for this case, since the URL is external and requires query parameters, there isn't really a baked-in solution. After all, a large part of the point of Apostrophe's asset-pushing mechanism is minification, which really doesn't apply here. Loading assets externally is... well... external.

So a block in your outerLayout makes perfect sense for your scenario.

Hope this is helpful!